# OutSystems TimeZone Conversion

Tags: time, timezone, zone, outsystems

I need a hand here

The default OutSystems timezone is UTC
There's an Action called ConvertFromTimeZone(1,2,3)

1- You write the Date and Time, no problem here.

2 & 3 - You have to write the SourceTimeZone and the DestinationTimeZone, these must be written in Text data type.

My question is: How exactly am I supposed to write it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GetSystemTimeZones to get the list of available timezones in the servers.

This post http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/16005/convertfromtimezone/#Post67485 shows the Identifier that uniquely identifiers a timezone.

Comment: He's answering my question there. Hehe

Answer (score 1):

Just one correction: the default timezone isn't UTC, but the timezone set in your application server.

The value you should use in the timezone code must be one of [Microsoft Time Zone Index Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) (column 'Name Of Time Zone')

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about timezone conversion here:
http://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-discussions/500/Time+Zone

Comment: I've been there too. Didnt really help

Answer (score 0):

you can use this action ConvertFromUTC(UTC_Datetime, "GMT Standard Time") it is from the Timezone extension.